# The error "defineNuxtConfig is not defined" occurs

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, tsconfig

Situation

```
npx nuxi init my-project-name
cd my-project-name
npm install
```

When I run this command, I get the error "defineNuxtConfig is not defined."

I have tried reinstalling node.js, but to no avail.

What could be the cause of this error?

Version

node: 18.15.0

nuxt: 3.3.2

npm: 9.5.0

Reinstall node.js
Reinstall npm, npx, typescript, nuxt global packages

Answer (score 7):

Substantiating on Matthew Dean's comment a bit, and in my case a warning appeared since I configured ESlint. However, the app should still run with this warning, well, as the doc suggests (https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/nuxt.config), the following solved it:

You can explicitly import defineNuxtConfig from nuxt/config if you prefer:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // My Nuxt config
})
```

Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was my installed Vue.js version was 2.17 and i needed to use vue 3 for my project. Go to terminal, write

```
npm list
```

if you see your Vue and Nuxt version lower than expected you may face this issue.
try to get latest version of Vue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2rXA.png)

Answer (score -1):

You have this on your nuxt config?

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3';

export default defineNuxtConfig({

});
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't change the results. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'`